# Determining target from gcc plugin

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

How can I determine which target architecture we are building for from gcc plugin?

I was thinking about using `TARGET_CPU_CPP_BUILTINS`, but the functions it expands to, e.g. `ix86_target_macros`, are not available in the plugin environment.

Edit: for now I've resorted to checking the presence of machine-specific option macros, e.g. `ix86_isa_flags`. This works, but it looks fragile.

Answer (score 0):

As I can correctly understand the question, you need to determine the target architecture GCC compiled for. There is a simple command `-dumpmachine`, it prints the compiler’s target machine, for example:

```
$ gcc -dumpmachine
x86_64-linux-gnu
```

or

```
$ riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -dumpmachine
riscv64-unknown-elf
```